# Create a folder and get its path after that using python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a folder inside of a selected folder, name it after the date of creation and get an absolute path of this newely created folder. My code is down below:

```
today = datetime.now()
dateAndTime = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
workingdir = os.path.dirname(os.mkdir(delovnaMapa + "/" + dateAndTime))
print(workingdir)
```

This code creates a folder inside of the selected one, but I get following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-f0c6828b61d4>", line 3, in <module>
    workingdir = os.path.dirname(os.mkdir(delovnaMapa + "/" + dateAndTime))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\ntpath.py", line 223, in dirname
    return split(p)[0]
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\ntpath.py", line 185, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a function call? You already have the path, it's `delovnaMapa + "/" + dateAndTime`...

Answer (score 1):

os.mkdir function creates a directory, its return is None.

For your work to be done, you should be using

`os.mkdir(delovnaMapa + "/" + dateAndTime)`

then, use

`os.path.dirname(delovnaMapa + "/" + dateAndTime)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It partly works, but the os.path.dirname reads the path as `os.path.dirname(delovnaMapa)` and not as `os.path.dirname(delovnaMapa + "/" + dateAndTime)`. I only get the path of "delovnaMapa".

Comment: @TimGregorčič I am on Windows. I have googled os.path.dirname, it said that it uses split() function. It removes the last element, that, if you use 'foo/bar', it will simply return 'foo'. But I used this code and it worked: You should be using `print(os.path.join(dev + "/" + date))` for proper usage

Comment: @Timko99 actually, `os.path.dirname` gives the parent directory of the "last item". Like, if you give `/home/user/doc1.txt`, it will give `/home/user`. maybe you want to use, `os.path.join` function?

Comment: @Timko99 Please ask if you need to!